# How to resolve Error CS1955 Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method in excel export

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application, I want to export to Excel using EPPlus package. I have this method inside a repository.

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public bool Successful { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    public Response(int statusCode, bool success, string msg, T data)
    {
        Data = data;
        Successful = success;
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Message = msg;
    }

    public Response()
    {
    }

    public static Response<T> Fail(string errorMessage, int statusCode = 404)
    {
        return new Response<T> { Successful = false, Message = errorMessage, StatusCode = statusCode };
    }

    public static Response<T> Success(string successMessage, T data, int statusCode = 200)
    {
        return new Response<T> { Successful = true, Message = successMessage, Data = data, StatusCode = statusCode };
    }

    public override string ToString() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
}
```

`ConvertAllCustomerExcel`:

```
private Response<string> ConvertAllCustomerExcel(IEnumerable<GetCustomersResponseDto> reports)
{
     byte[] fileContents;
     ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

     using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
     {
         // Set author for excel file
         package.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Japhet";
         // Set title for excel file
         package.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Customer List";
         var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");                 
         var currentRow = 1;               

         worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 1].Value = "First Name";
         worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 2].Value = "Last Name";
         worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 3].Value = "Email";
         worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 4].Value = "UserName";                

         // Style for Excel 
         worksheet.DefaultColWidth = 16;
         worksheet.Cells.Style.Font.Size = 16; 

         // Export Data from Table customers
         foreach (var report in reports)
         {
             currentRow++;
             worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 1].Value = report.FirstName;
             worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 2].Value = report.LastName;
             worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 3].Value = report.Email;
             worksheet.Cells[currentRow, 4].Value = report.UserName;
         }                 

         fileContents = package.GetAsByteArray();
     }             

     if (fileContents == null || fileContents.Length == 0)
     {
         return NoContent();
     }             

     return File(
         fileContents: fileContents,
         contentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
         fileDownloadName: "Customers.xlsx");
}
```

File has the `System.IO` namespace, and I know it works in a controller. But I am not using it in a controller, but will eventually call it there.

However, I got this error:

> Error CS1955 
> Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method

and `File` is highlighted.

Is there an alternative way of implementing file when not in controller, and how do I resolve it in C# ?

Comment: The `File` *type* in `System.IO` is *nothing* to do with the `File` *method* in the base class of controllers. If you want to use that method, your code *needs* to be in a controller derived class (or some form of trampoline/delegate passing it from caller to callee)

Comment: *Is there an alternative way of implementing file when not in controller, and How do I resolve it?* Not possible. *File has the System.IO namespace, and I know it works in a Controller.* This is incorrect. The `File` method is referred to [ControllerBase.File Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0), not the *System.IO*.

Comment: @YongShun - How do I get it resolved?

Answer (score 1):

`Controller.File` method simply returns new [FileContentResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) - so to fix just that part you need to create new FileContentResult by hand instead of using `File(...)` helper method (obviously you can't really cast it to your `Response<string>`, but it is not what is asked):

```
  FileContentResult r = new FileContentResult(
     fileContents,
     "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    {
      FileDownloadName  =  "Customers.xlsx"
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to reply of Alexei Levenkov
Your method is returning a METHOD name `FILE()`
while you are writing a method `RESPONSE<string> ConvertAllCustomerExcel()` to return a string type
that's why the compiler is saying :

*Error CS1955
Non-invokable member 'File' cannot be used like a method*

To resolve issue Match the return TYPE of Response and `return string;` or use `ActionResult()` to return a FILE Type. But as you said you're not in controller class so you can use `FileContentResult()`

```
public FileContentResult ConvertAllCustomerExcel(Parameters params) 
{
    //some logic to get all stuff
    return File(fileStream, attachment.ContentType, attachment.Name);
}
```

I hope it will work